# How to put MongoDB behind Express and execute arbitrary queries?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have an Express application. I would like to expose a route, eg. `/mongo` and allow users to connect to this route using a client (let's say NodeJS client). The users should be able to execute arbitrary queries, just as they would do normally.
My initial idea was to use some proxy, like `express-http-proxy` and leverage Mongo's HTTP interface and REST API, but in v3.6 [they removed both](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/#http-status-interface).

Is that possible?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Could we possibly explain all of how to write a REST interface here. NO. But it would be up to you to write it yourself or look and see if some other third party has released a REST interface that might suit your needs. But it's way to broad a question to describe here. Start something and ask questions about that instead.

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to expose the full database like this, except perhaps if the app is intended to be used by admins... Having said this, if you still want to implement, you may want to limit them to a specific collection or do some sanitizing... If you just want to pull data, I'd recommend using mongodbs aggregation framework, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/